# Не работает кликабельная легенда Altair 5.0.0rc1 Python

Tags: python, библиотеки, визуализация, графики

При построении графика в Altair 5.0.0rc1 в Jupiter Notebook пользуюсь данными из документации. Добавляю селектор чтобы можно было выделять данные щелчком на легенду.

Код такой:

```
year_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['year'], bind='legend')
pps_range = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=5500, step=100, name='Фильтр численности ППС: ')

pps_cutoff = alt.param(
    bind=pps_range,
    value=5500
)

base_chart1 = alt.Chart(
    univers_data
).add_params(
    pps_cutoff # добавление в чарт параметра
)

scatter_plot1 = base_chart1.mark_point(
).encode(
    x=alt.X('pk:Q', title = ['Количество студентов, человек'], axis=alt.Axis(grid = False)), # - количественный атрибут
    y=alt.Y('pps:Q', title = ['Численность ППС, человек'], axis=alt.Axis(grid = False)),
    color='year:N',
).add_selection(
   year_selection 
)


scatter_plot1
```

Выдает ошибку

> Javascript Error: The string contains invalid characters. This usually
> means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript
> console for the full traceback.

При этом если убрать

```
.add_selection(
       year_selection 
    )
```

График строится

[image: Вид графика]

Помогите, пожалуйста, что не так.

На атрибут `.add_params()` выходит ошибка

> Javascript Error: The string contains invalid characters. This usually
> means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript
> console for the full traceback.